# How to take data from a .txt file?

Tags: c++, file-io

I tried to write a little program that retrieves data from a .txt file and shows it in the terminal but I got an error. 
I have to say I am new to visual studio; until now i worked on code:blocks

I have tried the suggestion from the error code, adding the #include "pch.h" at the beggining but it still didn t work.

The error code is C1010 (if i build the code without line #include "pch.h"); If i build it with that line i recieve multiple error codes:

```
"1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(10): error C2065: 'ifstream': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(10): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'inFile'
1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(10): error C2065: 'inFile': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(11): error C2065: 'inFile': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(11): warning C4129: 'B': unrecognized character escape sequence
1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(11): warning C4129: 'D': unrecognized character escape sequence
1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(14): error C2065: 'inFile': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bogdan\documents\c & c++ programs\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file\writing and reading a txt file.cpp(15): error C2065: 'cout': undeclared identifier"

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\Users\Bogdan\Documents\UID.txt");

        int x;
    inFile >> x;
    cout << x; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: please let is know what the error code / text is.

Comment: And you need to escape your \ so replace \ with \\

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i forgot to tell that. The code is C1010 (if i build the code without line #include "pch.h"); If i build it with that line i recieve multiple error codes:

Comment: When asking about build errors, always include the *actual* errors, in full and complete, including any possible informational notes. And copy-pasted as text. So please *edit your question* to include that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I rewrote my question

Comment: You have neglected the namespace (Key term: scope resolution). `ifstream` should be `std::ifstream`. `cout` should be `std::cout`.

Comment: i tried to fix the formatting but now the actual error is hidden behind a scrollbar. Maybe you want to remove the filenames, I didnt want to modify the contents of your question

Comment: It s ok now, I ve fixed it! Thank you for your help and time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifstream` and `cout` are both part of the `std` namespace. You aren't `using namespace std`, so you need to include the namespace whenever you reference them. A fixed version of your code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\Users\Bogdan\Documents\UID.txt");

    int x;
    inFile >> x;
    std::cout << x; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Brandon! I added this line: using namespace std; (because i am not used with std::) and now it works...partially; In the txt file i have the number 123 but in the output it is something like -880513. I ll fix this one myself :D Thanks for the help

Comment: That looks like an uninitialized int. I'd bet the file is failing to open, which usually means the file path is wrong.

Comment: You were right. I modifyed the file path and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example in C++ show you how to open a file using fstream, after i add a loop while ( getline (myfile,line) ) that check if the filestream has a line, if it has a line then the program will print it cout << line << '\n'; if not the program will exit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main () {
  string line;
  std::ifstream myfile ("/path/to/file.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else std::cout << "Error unable to open file" << std::endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you changed? Why? Code-only answers encourages cargo-cult programming which is bad. Not to mention your program does a lot that the OP doesn't really ask about.

Comment: version without using using namespace std; to avoid pollutes the global namespace and increase compile time